# Cannot launch django with celery in Docker Compose v3

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./misc/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - /static:/static
    depends_on:
      - web

  web:
    restart: always
    image: celery-with-docker-compose:latest
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python /code/manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python /code/manage.py migrate && /code/run_gunicorn.sh"
    volumes:
      - /static:/data/web/static
      - /media:/data/web/media
      - .:/code
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./app:/deploy/app

  worker:
    image: celery-with-docker-compose:latest
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    command: bash -c "pip install -r /code/requirements.txt && /code/run_celery.sh"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - web

  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    privileged: true
    command: bash -c "sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1 && redis-server"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

When I run `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml cryptex` I got

```
Non-string key at top level: true
```

And `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml config` gives me

```
ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', the service name True must be a quoted string, i.e. 'True'.
```

I'm using latest versions of docker and compose. Also I'm new to compose v3 and started to use it for getting availability of docker stack command. If you see any mistakes or redudants in config file please, let me know. Thanks

Comment: Seems that the port must be a quoted string in service area. 
e.x: ports:
      - "80:80"

Answer (score 0):

you have to validate you docker compose file, is probably that the have low value inside

> Validating your file now is as simple as docker-compose -f
>   docker-compose.yml config. As always, you can omit the -f
>   docker-compose.yml part when running this in the same folder as the
>   file itself or having the